# how to list all directories for group has access to in unix/linux

Tags: linux, unix, directory

Is there a way to list all directories for group has access to in unix/linux. Or a way to list all groups along with directories for which the group has access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find all directories with execute permission (yes, execute as you need execute permission to a directory to be able to access files in it) that belong to group `group`.

```
find ${dir} -type d -group ${group} -perm -g=x -print
```

see man page of **find(1)** for details and examples of `-perm` option.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `ls -lahp | grep '/'` would do the job for you